# XPath Combining/Multiple

Tags: xpath

I'm using XPath to select elements of content and i want to select 2 elements, the problem is I dont know how to combine the 2 selectors into 1 query.

```
//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/img[@class=""]

//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/div/div[@class="quote"]
```

I thought I could do this by doing;

```
//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/img[@class=""] and //div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/div/div[@class="quote"]
```

or

```
//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/img[@class=""] | //div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/div/div[@class="quote"]
```

But none of these work.

Comment: The second shoul work if you combine two working xpath with `|`

Answer (score 0):

You forget the brackets:

This:

```
(//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/img[@class=""]|//div[@id="dle-content"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner"]/div[@class="mcontent_inner_box"]/div[@class="article"]/div/div[@class="quote"])
```

should work.